# Segfaulting on a simple program using managed dynamic storage

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I've tried asking a couple people I know but they were probably too busy to give me at advice on this.

I keep running into walls with the way alloc/dealloc are dealt
with. The following one is driving me nuts... this is a boiled down essence
of some code I have been trying to debug all week.

Here is what I think *should* be happening (but obviously is not):

- I allocate a pool
- I create an object and autorelease to put it in the current pool so
  it will dealloc when I release the pool.
- The test class has an NSString var that is only internal.
- The NSString is released in the dealloc method of that class.
- I release the pool, which does try to release the test object,
- It segfaults in the dealloc method as soon as it tries to release the
  NSString.

In the past I've managed to get buy by fiddling until the problem went away. However I have now reached the point of development where I need to be able to prove I have eliminated storage issues.

I have read masses of documentation over the last year on ObjC storage management.
Unfortunately, there seems to be some disagreement in how this all actually fits
together, and that confusion is not helpful to those of us who have not been part of
this managed storage process as it grew. If I am having difficulties (I used to write DSA's in assembly code for RTOS's), I can only imagine what others must be facing.

One thing that would be really useful is a manual on how to test your code to eliminate
this sort of fault. I am sure such information exists, and have run across a bit here and a bit there, but the pieces don't all fit together neatly. I've also been using enableDoubleReleaseCheck.

I left it out to keep the test case simple.

Here's CommandTest.m, a complete test case that results in:

```
./CommandTest
Release cmdline
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


/* Makefile strings:
   OBJC = gcc -g -fobjc-exceptions -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -I /usr/include/GNUstep

   CommandTest:    CommandTest.o $(OBJC) -g -o CommandTest CommandTest.o -lobjc -lgnustep-base */

#include <stdio.h>
```

## import

```
@interface Command:NSObject {NSString *cmdline;}
- (id)   init;
- (void) dealloc;
@end

@implementation Command
- (id) init {
  if (!(self = [super init])) {return nil;}
  cmdline = [NSString stringWithCString: "This is a test"];
  return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  printf ("Release cmdline\n");
  [cmdline release];
  printf ("Release cmdline done\n");
  [super dealloc];
}
@end

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  Command *cmd            = [[Command new] autorelease];

  @try {[pool release];}
  @catch (NSException *e){
    printf ("Fatal [%s] %s\n", [[e name] cString], [[e reason] cString]);}

  printf ("Done\n");
  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Advice would be *most* welcome and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is being double-released. `+[NSString stringWithCString:]` creates an autoreleased object. It is automatically put into the nearest autorelease pool.

When the pool is released, the string is too. Then, the string's owner sends `release` again, which causes your exception. (These two may actually happen in either order; it doesn't matter.)

From the point of view of the reference count, your `Command` object doesn't actually own the string, because it has not followed the NARC rule. It has not used any of `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, or `copy` on the string. The autorelease pool is the sole owner. Thus, it's an error for the `Command` to later send `release`.

The solution is to send `retain` to the autoreleased string when you create it -- then both the pool and the `Command` would have ownership, and would be required to send `release` later -- or to create it using `alloc`, as in `[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:]`. Then the `Command` would be the sole owner.

Comment: The scary part of that is... how do you know when an object created for internal use in a Class is already autoreleased or retained and when it is not? I'd thought the general rule was that if you allocate it, you release it.

Comment: By convention. If you create it with `new` or `alloc`, it's an owned reference. If you don't, then it's not your concern (but as a practical matter it's almost certainly in the autorelease pool). The rule is if you allocate it _using `alloc`_.

Comment: It looks like the relevant section of GNUStep's docs is here: http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_3.html#SEC43

Comment: Thanks. Using that modified mnemonic, I will start building my way back up to the original, far more complex code. In the original an array of strings created by a split is joined into a new line with a join and that line was then stored. I used the initWithCString to replicate the segfault in a simpler context. I will probably be back with more questions later so please bear with me. I really need to get the logic of this burned into me. I've got a rather large and mission critical project with a tight time line. Of course that's probably where all of you sit day to day as well.

Comment: Apple also has good writeups: //developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html Glad I could help. Good luck.

Comment: The alloc approach dies with NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: GSPlaceholderString(instance) does not recognize stringWithCString: but a retain does work in this case.

Comment: You can try clang ARC, and GNUstep mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
cmdline = [NSString stringWithCString: "This is a test"];
```

You're not retaining the object, so it's effectively returned with a 0 retain count and autoreleased soon after.